# Reading a configuration file for indexing job in azure function

Tags: c#, function, azure, media, indexer

I'm trying to make an Azure function for indexing an MP4 file. I'm looking for a method to read the configuration file that's needed for the Indexer. I have made a console application that's reading the configuration file from my harddisk and that's working perfect. But how do I read a file inside an Azure function?

For example:

```
EncodeFile(asset, @"e:\index.xml");

public static IAsset EncodeFile(IAsset asset, string configurationFile)
{
    IJob job = _context.Jobs.Create("Media Encoder Standard Job");

    string MediaProcessorName = "Azure Media Indexer";
    IMediaProcessor processor = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName(MediaProcessorName);

    string configuration = string.IsNullOrEmpty(configurationFile) ? "" : File.ReadAllText(**configurationFile**);

    ITask task = job.Tasks.AddNew("My encoding task",
        processor,
        **configuration**,
        TaskOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I read a file inside an Azure function?

We can put the file under the Azure function site.

For the Azure function App, if we create a function then it will create a folder on the WebApp with function name. If we want to read the file, we can put the file to the folder with Azure [kudu tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/)
 (https://yourfunctionsite.scm.azurewebsites.net). Azure web App D:\home is accessed. We can get more detail from [Azure WebApp Sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

> Every Azure Web App has a home directory stored/backed by Azure Storage. This network share is where applications store their content. This directory is available for the sandbox with read/write access.

[image]

In your case the code could be changed to:

```
string configuration = string.IsNullOrEmpty(configurationFile) ? "" : File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + @"\site\wwwroot\functionname\filename);
```

I also do a test for it. It works correctly on my side.

[image]